# queryable Odata Metadata or metadata parser to get subset of metadata only for selected fields

Tags: odata, metadata

i have a requirement to get only selected fields from ODATA, which i can achieve via $select query however i also want the metadata to have only those selected fields as there is a dependent requirement from an ETL tool.

Please let me know whether it is possible to somehow retrieve subset of metadata only for selected field or is there a standard ODATA metadata parser available in java/python/node which we can use to do the same.